# Using Cypher without Neo4j

Tags: java, cypher

How can I use Neo4j's Cypher query language without Neo4j ?

Our open source [project](http://cereebro.io) can build system dependency graphs, and we would like to allow users to run custom queries.

The graph does not need to be stored in a database, a simple in-memory cache is enough for most use cases.
We don't want to reinvent a graph query language though, and Cypher is the most user friendly.
I'm looking for a way to use Cypher directly on some kind of `Graph` Java object. The [API](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/3.3/community/cypher) seems decoupled enough to allow it.

Answer (score 2):

Cypher is an open **specification** (not a language) delivered over the [openCypher project](http://www.opencypher.org/).

[Here](http://www.opencypher.org/projects) you can find some open implementations of this specification including:

- [Neo4j Cypher DSL Implementation using Jetbrains MPS](https://github.com/corlab/Neo4jCypher)
- [A Cypher Parser written in C language](https://github.com/cleishm/libcypher-parser)
- and [a Cypher Parser written in Erlang](http://Cypher%20Parser%20written%20in%20Erlang)

I believe that if these implementations are not useful for you, then you can use the [ANTLR grammar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/Cypher.g4) of Cypher to generate a parser targeting another programming language. ANTLR can [generate parsers](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/targets.md) targeting Java, C#, JavaScript and others.

Answer (score 0):

Cypher is an open language, with the `opencypher` initiative : http://www.opencypher.org/

So you will find on the website, all you need to implement cypher (grammar, tck, ...).

Cheers

Comment: Writing our own Cypher implementation seems... disproportionate ? for our use case at least :) I'll check the various OSS projects and see if some part of it can do the trick.